# Error connecting Google Service API to retrieve message with end-user

Tags: php, google-api, gmail, gmail-api

I have follow some steps from Google's document about how to use Google Service API with PHP function.

I have done it so far by including Library and even the secret key. Finaly I reach to the last step but it asked me to get login. Exactly I want to retrieve my own message without asking for login because I have my own password and gmail's account already.

What is the problem with my code? could you tell me?

```
 public function retrieving_message()
        {
            $client_id  = '10521XXXX456-XXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com'; //Client ID
            $client_email = '1XXXXX56244-XXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com'; //Email Address
            $key_file_location = 'API Project-0f1afd2a0615.p12'; //key.p12
            $this->load->library('google');
            $client = new Google_Client();

            // Replace this with your application name.
            $client->setApplicationName("API Project");
            // Replace this with the service you are using.

            // We only need permissions to compose and send emails
            // $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly");
            $service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);

            $this->listMessages($service, 'hXXtpluXXXX.cam@gmail.com');

        }
```

Code to get Message :

```
function listMessages($service, $userId) {
      $pageToken = NULL;
      $messages = array();
      $opt_param = array();
      do {
        try {
          if ($pageToken) {
            $opt_param['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
          }
          $messagesResponse = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages($userId, $opt_param);
          if ($messagesResponse->getMessages()) {
            $messages = array_merge($messages, $messagesResponse->getMessages());
            $pageToken = $messagesResponse->getNextPageToken();
          }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
          print 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
      } while ($pageToken);

      foreach ($messages as $message) {
        print 'Message with ID: ' . $message->getId() . '<br/>';
      }

      return $messages;
    }
```

Out Put :

```
An error occurred: Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/hostplus.cam%40gmail.com/messages: (401) Login Required
```

Comment: For service accounts, 
Did you do domain wide delegation to your service account? developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount. This error happens when you have not authorized your service account to access data. check this link code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/… for sample php code in service account . Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24779138/can-we-access-gmail-api-using-service-account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code my help you:

```
$client->setApplicationName('API Project');
        $client->setScopes(implode(' ', array(Google_Service_Gmail::GMAIL_READONLY)));

        $client->setAuthConfigFile('key/client_secret.json');


        $client->setAccessType('offline');
```

You have to generate new json file but don't choose web or service, please check installed.