# Gmail Api authetication with application password

Tags: java, authentication, gmail-api

we have implemented successfully a Java Batch application that connects to a gmail account with oauth authentication in order to process and label user messages.

The problem we have now is that we need to access a corporate gmail account for which there is no user account to access directly but only delegated access using a different user.

We have been provided with and application password but we have been unable to get authenticated using it.
Using oauth with the user that have delegated access to the target account and switching to it we get the following error: "Delegated access is not allowed"

Is there any way to authenticate using gmail api using an application generated password to access with read/write permissions to a corporate gmail account?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you look into one of these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32848773/server-side-oauth-for-user-impersonation-via-gmail-api and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24779138/can-we-access-gmail-api-using-service-account/24795241#2479524?

Comment: The second link looks promising. I'll try it out and let you know. Thanks for your help.