# bypass gmail device verification

Tags: smtp, gmail, gmail-api

I have a gmail account that I want to use for one of our internal services. We have a server running and we want this gmail account to be used to send out an automated email to people who register.

Now, here's the problem. I have correctly configured my gmail id in the server and know that I am able to correctly ping the gmail smtp server. However,I always get stuck because gmail by default expects you to verify any new device you log in from using an OTP. In my case, this is the first time login from this server machine and hence this happens. I can see it in the logs as well - it brings up this device verification page.

Some questions:

1. Is there a way I can turn off this feature in gmail? I don't think this is the same as 2 step verification. I have turned it off. I have also enabled my gmail account to be accessible from non secure apps.
2. If not, is there a way to do the verification step via command line on my Linux server?
3. Any other smtp based email service I could use that does not have so many security features?
4. Lastly, I am doing this for a quick prototype. Therefore I am ok bypassing some of these aspects. However, I would definitely want to ensure that the access to my account is secure once this is productized. Any links on how we can do this from non google apps or services?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me you have an application that needs to work on your behalf and do some gmail-related tasks.

If that's the case, why not use the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api) with [Service Account impersonation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#creatinganaccount)?

In short, a service account can impersonate a real user. This is a process that does not require manual input after it's setup, so it's ideal for server-side usage, where you might not even have a UI to interact with.

Also, the Gmail API is much easier to set up than Gmail SMTP, and there are examples out there on how to do this with this setup. You can look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24779138/can-we-access-gmail-api-using-service-account) for some references on what it would take.