# when i try to list gmail threads using Gmail API i get GoogleJsonResponseException: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: java, google-api, gmail-api

I am trying to use GMAIL API to download attachments from my email account using OAuth 2.0 server to server Application. Here is my code:

```
    private static final String USER = "MYACCOUNT@gmail.com";
    private static String emailAddress = "XXXXXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
    {
       try {
              httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
              credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
              .setTransport(httpTransport)
              .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
              .setServiceAccountId(emailAddress)
              .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("myfile.p12"))
              .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(GmailScopes.GMAIL_READONLY))
              .build();
          }
          catch (IOException | GeneralSecurityException e)
          {
              throw new RuntimeException(e);
          }
    }
    // Create a new authorized Gmail API client
    Gmail service = new Gmail.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
        .setApplicationName(APP_NAME).build();

    // Retrieve a page of Threads
    ListThreadsResponse threadsResponse = service.users().threads().list(USER).execute();
      List<Thread> threads = threadsResponse.getThreads();

   // Print ID of each Thread.
    for (Thread thread : threads) {
      System.out.println("Thread ID: " + thread.getId());

}
```

I get the error at the threadsResponse call. These are the errors:

Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 500 Internal Server Error.

{
  "code" : 500,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Backend Error",
    "reason" : "backendError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Backend Error"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:312)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1049)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
    at core.crescent.gmail.GmailApiQuickstart.main(GmailApiQuickstart.java:192)

Comment: If you want to access a single user, you can use authentication for single user instead of service account. I don't think gmail API supports service account.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523003/error-500-backenderror-with-gmail-api-and-google-apis-node-client

Comment: I am using OAuth2 Server to server application [link](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount) because it seems like it's the only way to get authorization to access a gmail account without a user consent (without having to open browsers and do manual consent). Is there another way to accomplish this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could retry the request, with exponential backoff. Worked for  me. See https://developers.google.com/drive/web/handle-errors

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the issue and fixed it!

When setting up "Credential" (in the code I posted above). I needed to add .setServiceAccountUser(USER) sub-routine. By doing this, you make the link between the service account created and the GMAIL account you want to access.
I saw it earlier in https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount, but I was under the impression that it was only if you wanted to link with an account under a different domain name.

This fixed my issues. Thank you all for your responses