# Does the Gmail API support using OAuth Service Accounts?

Tags: python, oauth, google-api, gmail, gmail-api

I am trying to use the Gmail API with the Python Google Client library.

I have created a Service Account credential through the Google Developer Console.

I am then attempting to use those credentials like sO:

```
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials
client_email = '<sanitised>@developer.gserviceaccount.com'

with open("foobar-<sanitised>.p12") as f:
    private_key = f.read()
    credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(client_email, private_key, 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly')

from httplib2 import Http
http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())
from apiclient.discovery import build
gmail_server = build('gmail', 'v1', http=http_auth)
```

However, when I try to use the actual Gmail API, I get an HTTP 500 error:

```
In [13]: threads = gmail_server.users().threads().list(userId='me').execute()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HttpError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-a74134635cc3> in <module>()
----> 1 threads = gmail_server.users().threads().list(userId='me').execute()

/Users/victorhooi/.virtualenvs/kenny/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/util.pyc in positional_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    133         else: # IGNORE
    134           pass
--> 135       return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    136     return positional_wrapper
    137

/Users/victorhooi/.virtualenvs/kenny/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.pyc in execute(self, http, num_retries)
    721       callback(resp)
    722     if resp.status >= 300:
--> 723       raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
    724     return self.postproc(resp, content)
    725

HttpError: <HttpError 500 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/threads?alt=json returned "Backend Error">
```

A user mentioned here that apparently the "Service Accounts" do not support using the GMail API:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24645874/139137

Is anybody able to confirm if this is the case, or if it's documented by Google anywhere?

My assumption was that since the Service Account credentials were created through a user's Google Developer Console, it would just be associated with that user, and should work fine?

**EDIT**:

I should also mentioned I did try explicitly adding my client to the "Managing Client API Access" page in the Google Apps Admin Console:

[image]

However, I am still getting the HTTP 500 Backend Error.

Also, the help links on that page go to a OAuth 1.0 specific page - I have a suspicion that this page is only for OAuth 1.0, although it's not explicitly mentioned there.

**EDIT 2**

Also, I should mentioned that I tried using the Google API Explorer at:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/gmail/v1/gmail.users.messages.list?userId=me&_h=1&

using OAuth 2.0 and the interactive user flow, and it works fine (i.e. it lists emails).

**EDIT 3**

I tried adding the `sub` argument as suggested by Jay Lee.

On my own Google Apps domain, it does actually work:

```
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials
client_email = '<sanitised>@developer.gserviceaccount.com'
with open('foo-bar-<sanitised>.p12') as f:
    private_key = f.read()
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(client_email, private_key, 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly', sub='victorhooi@example.com')
from httplib2 import Http
http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())
from apiclient.discovery import build
gmail_server = build('gmail', 'v1', http=http_auth)
threads = gmail_server.users().threads().list(userId='me').execute()
```

And then threads gives me:

```
In [12]: threads
Out[12]:
{u'nextPageToken': u'00058094761552980977',
 u'resultSizeEstimate': 178,
 u'threads': [{u'historyId': u'8942',
   u'id': u'14abc26f1893823b',
   u'snippet': u''},
  {u'historyId': u'8822', u'id': u'14a4ffc2724e9384', u'snippet': u''},
  {u'historyId': u'8769', u'id': u'14a36a9c6f552af3', u'snippet': u''},
  {u'historyId': u'8716', u'id': u'14a31822f19bb161', u'snippet': u''},
  {u'historyId': u'8671', u'id': u'14a2bee13eb87c07', u'snippet': u''},
```

However, when I try using the sub argument on my corporate Google Apps domain, when I get to the following line:

```
gmail_server = build('gmail', 'v1', http=http_auth)
```

This gives me the error:

```
AccessTokenRefreshError: access_denied: Requested client not authorized.
```

I'm fairly certain that client does exist in the Google Developer's console, and the Gmail API is enabled. I'm just not sure why the `sub` argument triggers that error.

And then, if I try the same code using a different account on the corporate Google Apps domain, that hasn't been Delegated, I get:

```
AccessTokenRefreshError: unauthorized_client: Unauthorized client or scope in request.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using:

```
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(client_email, private_key,
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly', sub='user@domain.com')
```

where user@domain.com is the user you wish to impersonate.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did try it (see Edit 3 above), however, when I add that, it gives me a different error message ("AccessTokenRefreshError: access_denied: Requested client not authorized.")

Comment: You need to grant that service account access to your work domain:

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account

Make sure to use the same scopes when granting that you are requesting in your code.