# Gmail API service account

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, gmail-api, service-accounts

I want to read my gmail inbox using Gmail API. I need to use a service account due my application haven't user interaction.
I get a following error on request:

`"InnerException = {"Error:\"unauthorized_client\", Description:\"Unauthorized client or scope in request.\", Uri:\"\""} "`

**This is my code:**

```
        string applicationName = "Gmail API .NET";
        string[] scopes = { GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly };

        string certPath = "./XXXXXXXXXX.p12";
        string userEmail = "MYEMAIL@gmail.com";
        string serviceAccountEmail = "MYSERVICEACCOUNT...am.gserviceaccount.com";

        //Carga el certificado obtenido de 
        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certPath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
            new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
            {
                User = userEmail,
                Scopes = scopes
            }.FromCertificate(certificate)
        );

        if (credential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None).Result) <--- Here I get the error
        {
            GmailService gs = new GmailService(
                new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    ApplicationName = applicationName,
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential
                }
            );
        }
```

What am I doing wrong? Can anybody help me?

Regards

Comment: You need to configure your Gmail account to allow for POP3/SMTP access. You can do this in your Gmail settings online.

Comment: Thanks. I did but I get the same result :(

Comment: Try this one. https://ebstalimited.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017031473-How-to-a-create-Gmail-service-account You will also need G Suite for using service accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#service-account) about service account in .NET libraries. This documentation also provides you a sample code that you can follow on how to setup service account. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24779138/can-we-access-gmail-api-using-service-account/24795241#24795241) can also give you idea on how to access GMAIL API using Service Account.

Now, for the error that you receive, check this links if it can help you.

- [Does the Gmail API support using OAuth Service Accounts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810898/does-the-gmail-api-support-using-oauth-service-accounts)
- [Gmail Api return Unauthorized client or scope in request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37785048/gmail-api-return-unauthorized-client-or-scope-in-request)

Answer (score 1):

You can only use a service account to send emails for a GSuite account and not a gmail account.

If you have a gmail account you can use [3-legged OAuth2 authentication](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/oauth2/#oauth-3lo)
Or turn on 2FA, generate an [App Password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en#generate) and use that as seen [here](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/#2-single-connection)

If you ARE using a GSuite account you can use the ServiceAccount but you will have to make sure it has **G Suite Domain-wide Delegation** as described [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#creatinganaccount) and then you need to give access to the GSuite Domain as described [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the sample code from Google for this function?

```
  using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1;
 using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data;

 // ...

 public class MyClass {

   // ...

 /// <summary>
 /// Retrieve a Message by ID.
 /// </summary>
 /// <param name="service">Gmail API service instance.</param>
 /// <param name="userId">User's email address. The special value "me"
 /// can be used to indicate the authenticated user.</param>
 /// <param name="messageId">ID of Message to retrieve.</param>
 public static Message GetMessage(GmailService service, String userId, String messageId)
 {
     try
     {
         return service.Users.Messages.Get(userId, messageId).Execute();
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
     }

     return null;
 }

 // ...

}
```

Have you tried the API explorer here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get#net 
and entered your request information? Did it work from the API page?

Comment: From Google test works fine.
I think that the problem is about authentication. I get this error {"Error:\"unauthorized_client\", Description:\"Unauthorized client or scope in request.\", Uri:\"\""}  when I call this method credential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None).Result

Answer (score 0):

Service accounts cannot access @gmail.com mailboxes.  You must use one of the other supported OAuth 2.0 authorization scenarios described at https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2.

See
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39534420/3377170 for more details.

Comment: I managed to work with an old Gmail account. The tests were done with a new account. Is it possible that if the old accounts allow you to use service accounts?

Comment: There was a loophole in the past that allowed service accounts access to @gmail.com accounts, but it has been closed.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/39534420/3377170.